# Truffle (4.0) test multiple contracts

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-migration, truffle-compile

I'm trying to test a contract that wrote and compiled, and I need to use another deployed contract to test it. I am writing a test for a specific contract and trying to invoke another deployed contract:

```
contract('Vault', accounts => {
  it('should be able to see the other contract.', async () => {
    const instance = await Vault.deployed()
    const owner = await instance.admin.call()
    assert.equal(owner, accounts[0], `contract owner was not ${accounts[0]}`)
    console.log(await HumanStandardTokenFactory.deployed())
})
```

which should work, but it I get the error:

```
Error: HumanStandardTokenFactory has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch).
```

I am using the new `truffle develop` command instead of TestRPC. When I run `migrate`, I can see the addresses of all the contracts being populated properly. I installed the contract through EthPM. In the truffle console I can even type:

```
truffle(develop)> HumanStandardTokenFactory.deployed().then(instance => console.log(instance.address))
0x82d50ad3c1091866e258fd0f1a7cc9674609d254
```

I'm thinking this has something to do with the "clean-room" environment, but everyone else seems to have gotten past this issue. My migration file is as follows:

```
const Vault = artifacts.require('./Vault.sol')
const HumanStandardTokenFactory = artifacts.require(
  'tokens/HumanStandardTokenFactory'
)

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(HumanStandardTokenFactory)
  deployer.deploy(Vault)
}
```

Is there any way I can get the deployed version of this contract into my tests?

Comment: With truffle I'd first try removing the build/ folder. And make a deploy again. It just happened too many times that a broken artifact caused tests failures.

Comment: 1. Do you see HumanStandardTokenFactory.json in your build folder?
2. Do you see "Compiling HumanStandardTokenFactory.." in your console output when you run `test`?

Comment: @ulu yes to both. I got around it by manually deploying the contracts as part of the test setup.